# Rendering problem with Java Script array with objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am having problem to render below array with objects.

```
var newList = '{appointmentList}';
var apptList = JSON.parse(newList);
alert(newList);
alert result:
[{
   "userId":"0051a000002BHA7AAO",
   "subject":"Appcal blk",
   "startDateTime":"2017-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
   "profileId":"a1C1a000000zkWXEAY",
   "location":"Rm # 23-C48 in 177 Huntington Ave",
   "id":"a160j000000BOgDAAW",
   "endDateTime":"2017-07-03T19:00:00.000Z",
   "duration":30,
   "categoryType":"30-min Appts (shown on Public Calendar)",
   "bookedSlotList":[],
   "availableSlotList":
       [{
          "startDateTime":"2017-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
          "endDateTime":"2017-07-03T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "startDateTime":"2017-07-03T18:30:00.000Z",
          "endDateTime":"2017-07-03T19:00:00.000Z"
        }],
   "availableBlockList":
       [{
          "startDateTime":"2017-07-03T18:00:00.000Z",
          "endDateTime":"2017-07-03T19:00:00.000Z"
       }],
   "availability":"Any",
   "appointmentTypeList":
       [
         "Phone"
       ]
 }];
```

I am using for loop, but having problem with availableSlotList array.

```
if(apptList.length > 0) {
for(var i=0;i<apptList.length;i++) {
    var catg = (catMap[apptList[i].categoryType] == 'Individual') ? '' : 'none';
    var apptSize = JSON.stringify(apptList[i].availableBlockList);
    //alert(apptSize+'---'+i);
    var showAppt = (apptList[i].availableBlockList.length == 0) ? 'none' : '';
    var noAppt = (apptList[i].availableBlockList.length == 0) ? '' : 'none';

    html += '<table width="100%" style="font-size:13px;"><tr><td>'
    html += '<apex:outputText value="' + apptList[i].startDateTime +' - '+ apptList[i].startDateTimee + '" style="font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:2px;" />  ';
    html += '<apex:outputText value="(' + tzName + ')" style="font-weight: bold;" /></td></tr>';
    html += '<tr style="display:' + catg + '">';
    html += '<td class="tabLine" style="display:' + showAppt + '"><apex:outputText value="Appointments available during: " />';
    html += '</td></tr></table>';

    for(var j;j<apptList[i].availableSlotList) {
        alert(apptList[i].availableSlotList.startDateTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript and Visualforce that way; Visualforce tags are rendered on the server, not the client. Use normal HTML elements instead.

Comment: I am not having problem with tags. I am having problem loop array objects like availableSlotList and availableBlockList.

Answer (score 0):

See sfdcfox's comment: you can only use plain HTML tags in this logic e.g. just a `<span>` in place of `<apex:outputText>`.

On the question of looping, based on the JSON and the name, that field is an array so you need to loop over its elements:

```
    for (var j = 0; j < apptList[i].availableSlotList.length; i++) {
        alert(apptList[i].availableSlotList[j].startDateTime);
    }
```

It is best to reduce the repeated array indexing for code clarity (and to not waste execution time) by adding some local variables:

```
for (var i = 0; i < apptList.length; i++) {
    // Use appt in place of all apptList[i] references
    var appt = apptList[i];
    ...
    for (var j = 0; j < appt.availableSlotList.length; j++) {
        var availableSlot = appt.availableSlotList[j];
        alert(availableSlot.startDateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, 

Thanks for your response. I tried the way you have mentioned. But it's not looping. I tried below way, first time I am seeing value but loop not closing and printing undefined. Please check the data structure again.

for(var j in appt.availableBlockList) {
   var block = appt.availableBlockList[j];
   alert(block.startDateTime);
}

Comment: Hey Keith, I updated my question. Please check again.